# javascript string.indexOf(array) no funciona con strings largos

Tags: javascript, array, string

Estuve buscando esto un buen rato pero todas las preguntas eran distinta a la mía.

Estoy intentando buscar un string en un array donde los strings dentro del array contienen mas de una palabra, por ejemplo:

```
var array = ["hola soy un string", " asd hola asd " , "hola"]
```

si yo hago:

```
array.indexOf("hola")
```

Me devolvera 2, okay.

Pero, si mi array es de esta forma:

```
var array = ["hola asd", "asdasd hola", "aaxs hola asdxas"]

array.indexOf("hola");
```

no me devuelve nada a pesar que "hola" esta, por que es esto?

También lo intente de esta forma:

```
array.map(function(i) { return i; }).indexOf("hola");
```

Pero mas de lo mismo, no funciono.

Comment: sino me equivoco la función indexOf te devuelve la posición del elemento que sea igual al buscado, no que contenga a ese elemento [documentación](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp)

Comment: Si, es que yo me confundí porque por ejemplo cuando busco "hola asd".indexOf("hola") este lo encuentra. Y pensé que con arrays funcionaba de igual manera pero tengo que loopear el array para lo que yo quiero.

Comment: Exacto, para cada elemento del array deberías hacer un `indexOf()` para comprobar si lo encuentra

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Array.indexOf( )` devuelve la primera coincidencia **exacta** dentro de un Array.

```
[ 'hola', 'adios' ].indexOf( 'hola' ) => 0
[ 'hola', 'adios' ].indexOf( 'ios' ) => -1
```

No te queda mas remedio que recorrer el Array entero, elemento a elemento, mediante un bucle:

```
idx = -1;
while( curr = Array[++idx] )
 if( COMPROBACIÓN QUE BUSCAS ) {
  ...
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Si miras la documentacin de [`indexOf`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) puedes ver que te devuelve el indice de la primer posicion  que encuentra con el `string` que buscas.

ej:

```
var str = "Hello world, welcome to the universe.";
var n = str.indexOf("e"); // n =  1
```

Pero tu lo aplicas a un `array`, entonces te devuelve el indice del elemento que coincide con lo que buscas. Cuando tenias el array con un elemento `"hola"` te lo encontraba, pero luego al tener `"aaxs hola asdxas"` no te lo encuentra

Comment: Si, apenas publique la pregunta pense que seria por eso que dices.
Si lo hago loopeando el array funciona, pero no se si es la forma correcta de buscar un string en un array

Comment: Si no me equivoco esto es `java`... nada que ver con `javascript`